# Why Exception Raised while Retrieving the Youtube Elements using iterator in Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I Retrieved  Youtube comments  and write into a file using Jsoup 
Mycode:

```
Document docComments;
BufferedWriter bw1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                "D:\\chuchutvlink1.txt"));

    docComments = Jsoup
                .connect(
                        "https://apis.google.com/u/0/wm/4/_/widget/render/comments?usegapi=1&first_party_property=YOUTUBE&href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DdWO9uP_VJV8%26list%3DTLDVdYZggWP-Q&owner_id=BnZ16ahKA2DZ_T5W0FPUXg&query=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DdWO9uP_VJV8&stream_id=UCBnZ16ahKA2DZ_T5W0FPUXg&substream_id=dWO9uP_VJV8&view_type=FILTERED&width=826&youtube_video_acl=PUBLIC&viewer_id=UCI7Gw-Kd1PkeBDQ7C33kN9A&hl=en_US&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com&search=%3Fv%3DdWO9uP_VJV8%26list%3DTLDVdYZggWP-Q&hash=&gsrc=1p&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fabc-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Dgapi.gapi.en.T4EayPRcrOA.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAItRSTOp4ORGjvVzLjTlu0PIOZx2FtcWuA#_methods=onPlusOne%2C_ready%2C_close%2C_open%2C_resizeMe%2C_renderstart%2Concircled%2Cdrefresh%2Cerefresh%2Confirsttimeplusonepromo%2Conthumbsup%2Contimestampclicked%2Conshareboxopen%2Conready%2Conallcommentsclicked&id=I0_1417526304794&parent=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com&pfname=&rpctoken=63150800")
                        .get();
 Elements userComments = docComments.select("h3[class=Mpa]");
        Elements userName = userComments.select("span[class=Ub gna]");
        Elements userCommentsTime = docComments.select("span[class=PL]");
        Elements userLink = userComments.select("a");
        Elements userContent = docComments.select("div[class=Ct]");
        Elements usercommentsLike = docComments
                .select("span[class=uPc bmd]");
        Elements userReply = docComments.select("div[class=fR]");

        Iterator<Element> itrUserName = userName.iterator();
        Iterator<Element> itrCommentsTime = userCommentsTime.iterator();
        Iterator<Element> itrUserLink = userLink.iterator();
        Iterator<Element> itrUserContent = userContent.iterator();
        Iterator<Element> itrUserCommentsLike = usercommentsLike.iterator();
        Iterator<Element> itrViewReply = userReply.iterator();

        while (itrUserName.hasNext() || itrCommentsTime.hasNext()
                || itrUserLink.hasNext() || itrUserContent.hasNext()
                || itrUserCommentsLike.hasNext() || itrViewReply.hasNext()) {

            // System.out.println("count"+count);
            System.out.print("Name Of The User:  "
                    + itrUserName.next().text() + "   ");
            System.out.println(itrCommentsTime.next().text());
            System.out.println("userCommandsLink:  "
                    + itrUserLink.next().attr("href"));
            System.out.println("Content :" + itrUserContent.next().text());
            System.out.println("Like : "
                    + itrUserCommentsLike.next().text());
            System.out.println(itrViewReply.next().text() + "\n");
              bwriter.write("Name Of The User:  " +
              itrUserName.next().text() + "   "); 
              bwriter.newLine();
              bwriter.write(itrCommentsTime.next().text());
              bwriter.newLine(); bwriter.write("userCommandsLink:  " +
              itrUserLink.next().attr("href")); bwriter.newLine();
              bwriter.write("Content :" + itrUserContent.next().text());
              bwriter.newLine(); bwriter.write("Like : " +
              itrUserCommentsLike.next().text());

        }
         bwriter.close();
    } catch (Exception to) {
        to.printStackTrace();
    }
```

While i run this code Exception Occurred

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
    at Link1.main(Link1.java:116)
```

Comment: It seems that number of elements you are iterating is not the same for each iterator (for instance in `usercommentsLike` and `userReply`), but in your loop you checked if at least one iterator has some elements left, and if it does you are trying to read elements from all iterators despite fact that there may be no elements left for them.

Comment: values are printed in console but last iteration it shows on Exception

Name Of The User:  Baby Games Toys & ABC Songs   2 weeks ago
userCommandsLink:  http://www.youtube.com/profile_redirector/117481903552750900420
Content :Great Video :) keep it up?
Like : 16
Elif Karada? 1 day ago


 And so on ............

Finally

java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
    at Link1.main(Link1.java:116)

Comment: @Pshemo has already answered you. Change this `itrUserName.hasNext() || itrCommentsTime.hasNext()
                || itrUserLink.hasNext() || itrUserContent.hasNext()
                || itrUserCommentsLike.hasNext() || itrViewReply.hasNext()` to this -----> `itrUserName.hasNext() && itrCommentsTime.hasNext()
                && itrUserLink.hasNext() && itrUserContent.hasNext()
                && itrUserCommentsLike.hasNext() && itrViewReply.hasNext()`

Comment: In the above code 
 docComments ="The above URL";